# mysql query to select max value of each group if the maximum value is greater than all the other values of the group

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I have a table named tab1 like this:

| id | obj | col2 | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | obj1 | item1 | 2 |
| 2 | obj2 | item2 | 5 |
| 3 | obj1 | item3 | 4 |
| 4 | obj2 | item1 | 5 |
| 5 | obj3 | item4 | 2 |
| 6 | obj3 | item2 | 1 |

How to find the row with the maximum value for each object in the obj column. The maximum value of an object should be strictly greater than the other values of of the object. 
 
The output should be like this:

| id | obj | col2 | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | obj1 | item3 | 4 |
| 5 | obj3 | item4 | 2 |

```
SELECT id,obj,col2,max(val) 
FROM tab1
GROUP BY obj
```

| id | obj | col2 | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | obj1 | item3 | 4 |
| 2 | obj2 | item2 | 5 |
| 5 | obj3 | item4 | 2 |

I tried this query but the output includes the obj2 whose max value isn't strictly greater than the second max value (both the max and the second max value of obj2 is 5)

Comment: How to treat objects that only has a single entry/row in table? Should they be included in output or not?

Comment: If you are using MySQL 8.0, see `RANK()` versus `DENSE_RANK()`

Answer (score 0):

Using `DENSE_RANK` as mentioned by @Rick James.

```
select id, obj, col2, val,cnt from (
   select *, 
   dense_rank() over (partition by obj order by val) rn,
   count(val) over (partition by obj,val) cnt,
   count(val) over (partition by obj) cnt1
   from max_tab) X
where
X.rn <> 1
AND X.cnt = 1
OR X.cnt1 = 1;
```

Adjust the clause `x.cnt1`, as per requirements related to objects with single row.

Refer fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=770f1620a3de144a64d176ec590f5488).